# How SLF4J-API classloading gives preference to bindings over dummy?

Tags: java, classloader, slf4j

If you look at the source code for slf4j-api (any modern version, say, 1.7.5), there is a `LoggerFactory` class with the following method:

```
private static Set findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet() {
    // use Set instead of list in order to deal with  bug #138
    // LinkedHashSet appropriate here because it preserves insertion order during iteration
    Set staticLoggerBinderPathSet = new LinkedHashSet();
    try {
        ClassLoader loggerFactoryClassLoader = LoggerFactory.class
                .getClassLoader();
        Enumeration paths;
        if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
            paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        } else {
            paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader
                    .getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
        }
        while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL path = (URL) paths.nextElement();
            staticLoggerBinderPathSet.add(path);
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Util.report("Error getting resources from path", ioe);
    }
    return staticLoggerBinderPathSet;
}
```

This is called when you call any `Logger` method (debug, info, warn, error, etc.) and the SLF4J binding has *not* yet been initialized. It's how SLF4J determines which binding to use at runtime.

Basically, one way to write a proper binding for SLF4J is to implement your own `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` class. However, the `slf4j-api` JAR also comes with it's own dummy `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` implementation, probably to prevent compiler errors during SLF4J development (or to act as a no-op fallback if no such `StaticLoggerBinder` is provided by the binding).

Hence, if you have `slf4j-api-1.7.5` and `slf4j-simple-1.7.5` on your runtime classpath, then the first time you go to use, say, `Logger#info(String)`, the `StaticLoggerBinder` defined in the `slf4j-simple` JAR will be selected *over* the `StaticLoggerBinder` defined in the `slf4j-api` JAR.

**I'm trying to understand how this "preference"/prioritization (of binding impl over api impl) works.** How does the above method first choose the binding's `StaticLoggerBinder` over the dummy `StaticLoggerBinder` provided in `slf4j-api`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The dummy StaticLoggerBinder is simply not included in the slf4j-api jar file.

See the pom.xml in the slf4j-api source code [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/pom.xml).  The dummy binder gets deleted.